# xcodebuild resolves dependency, but can't import the package

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

I have a simple command line application, written in swift 5.3, which uses the ArgumentParser package from Apple.

It builds and runs **just fine** from within Xcode (12.4). However, if I run xcodebuild, as such:

```
xcodebuild -target mailfilter
```

It gives this error:

```
/Users/hacksaw/Documents/src/mailfilter/mailfilter/main.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'ArgumentParser'
import ArgumentParser
       ^
```

The relevant project info:

```
% xcodebuild -list
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list

Resolve Package Graph

Resolved source packages:
  swift-argument-parser: https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser @ 0.3.2

Information about project "mailfilter":
    Targets:
        mailfilter

    Build Configurations:
        Debug
        Release

    If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used.

    Schemes:
        mailfilter


% xcodebuild -version
Xcode 12.4
Build version 12D4e
```

So, what command line ought I run for it to build correctly?

Comment: Have you tried supplying the 'scheme' parameter in addition to the 'target'? Assuming the scheme name matches the target name: `xcodebuild -scheme mailfilter -target mailfilter`

Comment: Well, that worked, which is frustrating, because there is only one scheme.

Comment: Great... I dig a bit to see if I can get you a definitive answer on why the scheme is necessary. The way I think about it, a _scheme_ defines the build process around the _target_, which in this case would include knowledge of how to correctly build & link the `ArgumentParser` package.

Comment: Cool. I'm wondering if this is a minor bug.

Answer (score 2):

So the (still unsatisfying) answer to this is indeed that `-scheme` needs to be included, so this works:

```
xcodebuild -scheme mailfilter -target mailfilter
```

An article I read somewhere said something about xcodebuild having a "legacy" mode which is invoked if you don't include a `-scheme` argument, but didn't go into detail.

I'd love a more complete answer to this, but for now, I'm leaving it.